# can not display the dialog when load both file .js or .html?

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with this problem. When I coded this very simple javascript code from head first javasript book, they said to me that I must saved it as the name battle.js and run it, but after that, they said to me that I must run it as the name battle.html. Here is the code

```
var location1 = 3;
var location2 = 4;
var location3 = 5;
var guess;
var hits = 0;
var guesses = 0;
var isSunk = false;
while (isSunk == false) {
guess = promt("Ready, aim, fire! (enter a number from 0-6):")
if (guess < 0 || guess > 6) {
alert("Please enter a valid cell number!");
} else {
guesses = guesses + 1;
if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3) {
alert("HIT!");
hits = hits + 1;
if (hits == 3) {
isSunk = true;
alert("You sank my battleship!");
}
} else {
  alert("MISS");
}
}
}
var stats = "You took " + guesses + " guesses to sink the battleship, " +
"which means your shooting accuracy was " + (3/guesses);
alert(stats);
```

As they described, it must appear a dialog and we can enter something into that, but when I ran it, nothing appeared.

I just a newbie with javascript, could you please give me some ideas ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has typing mistake. replace `promt` to `prompt`

```js
var location1 = 3;
    var location2 = 4;
    var location3 = 5;
    var guess;
    var hits = 0;
    var guesses = 0;
    var isSunk = false;
    while (isSunk == false) {
        guess = prompt("Ready, aim, fire! (enter a number from 0-6):")
        if (guess < 0 || guess > 6) {
            alert("Please enter a valid cell number!");
        } else {
            guesses = guesses + 1;
            if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3) {
                alert("HIT!");
                hits = hits + 1;
                if (hits == 3) {
                    isSunk = true;
                    alert("You sank my battleship!");
                }
            } else {
                alert("MISS");
            }
        }
    }
    var stats = "You took " + guesses + " guesses to sink the battleship, " +
        "which means your shooting accuracy was " + (3 / guesses);
    alert(stats);
```

Comment: Thanks for repair my code, but when I copied your code and ran it, it said to me this error
"Object expected ... Code : 800A138F ... Source : Microsoft JScripit runtime error". So, what is this problem ?

Comment: [Microsoft Jscript runtime error](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error/e989ae71-7871-4f3c-9460-542d36728b89)